# Java: How to get greatest and similar sized Strings in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop, palindrome

The task seems pretty simple I have a **txt** file that I've imported fine, but I need to get the Array length which I've done but then I need to get the greatest length but on top of that I also need to get the arrays that have similar lengths.

For instance down below it is sorting the string but it only produces the greatest length/value:

```
int max = 0;
      String finalStrings = "";
      for (String r : rWord) {
          if (r.length() > max) {
              max = r.length();
              finalStrings = "Largest palindrome are: " + r + ", ";
          }
      }
```

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3iE8NHMH) -Full Code

So in that case what would be the best way to go about getting a String Arrays greatest and similar values?

Comment: Chuck the first `String` into a `List<String>`. If the second `String` is longer than that currently in the `List` - maybe keep a `length` variable - then `clear` the `List` and add the new, longer `String`. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

By 'similar' I assume you mean Arrays with the same length as the one with the longest length? If that's the case you can store all your Arrays in a `List` of `Array` i.e. `List<String[]>`

Comment: Ok, I sorta get it.. But won't that just sort that wont give me largest and its similar others.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, are you asking how to get the largest value? There's a few ways to go about your task (assuming I've understood the goal). One option is as you iterate through `rWord` you could add each `String` with its number of characters into a `Map` e.g. `Map<Integer, List<String>>, once you've finished iterating you retrieve the largest key and the collection of Strings to go with it.